# Will using the React props spread operator significantly slow-up my application?

Tags: reactjs

When passing props down into a React component I am currently of doing this:

```
<MyComponent 
    {...this.props}
    foo=foo
    bar=bar
/>
```

`foo` and `bar` are props that I know `MyComponent` will need. However, in most cases `MyComponent` also has components within it that need props from higher components, hence I use the `{...this.props}` operator to pass them forward. Should I be doing this, or should I be listing out exactly the props that the child components of `MyComponent` will need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a state management like Flux, Redux or Mobx (i think, haven't used Mobx at all) to combat this problem of passing props through multiple levels without the intermediate components needing them.

You should be passing only the props exactly needed down to the child. I read a great post on github about this but can't find it.

It's just hard to manage when your app grows and it's really an abuse of the Es6 spread syntax operator (i.e it makes it easy short term to pass props down, but long term you still have the problem, you are just masking it). Not sure if it slows down application but it will re-render all child components again if the prop changed which is unnecessary.

For example when using Redux you can "connect" components to a global state (think databases) and pass them through as props for whichever components you want and bypass components having to forward props to child components.

It's hard at first to learn but 1000% worth it.

Comment: Great advice and answers some questions about what i had assumed Redux might do.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in only the props needed, or implement a container component that only passes in the props needed. Or you can implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) on your component. The easiest way to get performance is to only pass in the required props though.